# How to ignore nulls or empty fields when validating columns/fields in SQL query

Tags: sql

I am trying to validate a field before inserting it into a table. The validation works fine but if the value is null it says it's invalid and does not insert. How to ignore nulls?
Help is highly appreciated

```
INSERT INTO XYZ

SELECT colA, colB, colC
FROM tableDEF w
WHERE
 ( (SUBSTRING(w.colA,1,1)='5' OR SUBSTRING(w.colA,1,1)='1' ) AND LEN(w.colA)=9 )
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Please show the EXACT error messages also.  We are not mind readers.

Comment: GypZyKing, could you answer some of these questions so we can better help you?

Comment: This is SQL Server 2012

Comment: @OldProgrammer I wasn't getting any error, it was just that the fields were not being inserted as one of the conditions was false because it was considering NULL as a invalid input. All I had to do was ignore the NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could use something like:

```
Where
   ... 
   and colA is not Null 
   and colB is not Null
   and colC is not Null
```

or, depending on your needs, change your null values to 'N/A' using `NVL(...)`

```
Nvl(ColA, 'N/A') as colA,
Nvl(ColB, 'N/A') as colB,
Nvl(ColC, 'N/A') as colC
```

This will show the field as either what is in the column or the string 'N/A'.

Both solutions are for `Oracle` and I can update the solution if it for another flavor of SQL.

Comment: I was able to make it work by using ISNULL. This is the working version.   (( (SUBSTRING(isNULL(w.colA,''),1,1)='5' OR SUBSTRING(ISNULL(w.colA,''),1,1)='1' ) AND LEN(w.colA)=9) OR w.colA is null )  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks. NVL gave me the clue.